# Set up single event handler for multiple buttons

Tags: c#

Hi im practically new to C# i usually program with c++ so please bear with me. I am coding an application and i have 10 buttons, 5 of which which are practically doing the same thing. Currently I have 5 event handlers doing the same thing. How can I change this to a single even handler with if statements. Also my problem is that even though the methods of each button are the same i have some small differences from one to another as described below:

button 1 copared with button 5
button 2 copmpared with button 6
button 3 compared with button 7 and so on

How can i tackle this small difference in each case?

Thankyou so much

Comment: WPF ? Winform ? If WPF maybe you should look at MVVM and ICommand, Bind each button to the same command, and just pass a CommandParameter to know from witch button you come.

Answer (score 2):

```
button.SomeEvent += SomeHandler

void SomeHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Button b = (Button)sender; //get the specific button that was pressed
   ...
}
```

Use the += operator to add a method to an event and simply add the same method.

Comment: I would change this to say that the events should be declared / assigned in the Designer, rather than in the code-behind, but it will produce the same result.

Comment: @JoeBrunscheon - Why?  If there is no difference why would it matter?

Comment: I don't get why it matters either.

Comment: There is a difference, but the end result of an event handler being hooked up is the same. Event handlers in the designer let you navigate to those implementations in the code-behind by double-clicking on the buttons, as well as providing a proper reporting in the designer event property fields of the actual event handler assigned to the event. If you assign the event handler in code-behind only, there is no indication in the designer that an event handler is hooked up to the Button_Click event for each of those buttons, and navigation to the handler doesn't work.

Comment: I wouldn't click on a button in a designer because if it doesn't have an event it will create one.

Comment: BTW I would add this to the answer as soon as OP clarifies the tech he is using. As is the answer is valid for Win Forms, WPF and Web Forms

Answer (score 0):

You could set them all to the same handler, get the button that called it, check the id in an if statement and do different actions -- OR -- you could use the much more common refactor that looks like this:

```
void Button1Action(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   // do stuff for button 1 here

   SharedCode();
}

void Button2Action(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   // do stuff for button 2 here

   SharedCode();
}

void Button3Action(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   // do stuff for button 3 here

   SharedCode();
}


void Button4Action(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   // do stuff for button 4 here

   SharedCode();
}

void SharedCode()
{

    // do stuff for all buttons

}
```